# Using JsonUtility.FromJson to deserialize JSON in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

This is my sample JSON:

```
{"data":[{"id":141,"layoutLabel":"Sameer","hasCustomProb":1},
{"id":214,"layoutLabel":"abc","hasCustomProb":0}],"status":200}
```

This is the class I made

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerInfo
{
    public string [] data;
    public int status;
}
```

This is how I get "status" from JSON:

```
PlayerInfo P = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerInfo>(json);
Debug.Log(P.status) //returns 200
```

Can someone help me out can I get and save the data array or maybe get data.id and data.hasCustomProb? I am new to C# and unity.

Comment: data isn't type string[]. In your sample JSON it is an array of objects that each have an "id","layoutLabel", and "hasCustomProb" properties.

Comment: Aren't these questions allowed to be asked at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your class should look like this

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerInfo
{
    public List<ActData> data;
    public int status;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class ActData
{
    public int id;
    public string layoutLabel;
    public int hasCustomProb;
}
```

Comment: Except that you have to remove `{ get; set; }` from all of the variables. `JsonUtility` cannot work with that.

Comment: @Programmer you are right. I wanted to sure if `Serializable` attribute is required as i just edited this answer?

Comment: Yup, that too or OP will get empty result.