# Cannot Serialize and Deserialize JSON in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

I have tried Serializing and Deserializing JSON in Unity using `JsonUtility` and `Newtonsoft.Json`. But neither of them works as expected.

- The issue with `JsonUtility` is it gives empty string when converting object to JSON. When converting JSON string to custom class object, and printing class's `object.value` it prints empty string. Irony is that it does not give any error.
- The issue with `Newtonsoft.Json` is it does not work with Android and iOS builds and builds that uses IL2CPP.

**C# Code**

```cs
public class AddUsers : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void ConvertToJSONSample()
    {
        UserDetails userDetails1 = new UserDetails()
        {
            Id = "0001",
            Name = "John"
        };

        string JsonString = JsonUtility.ToJson(userDetails1);
        print(JsonString); ;

        UserDetails userDetails2 = JsonUtility.FromJson<UserDetails>(JsonString);
        print("User's Name is: " + userDetails2.Name);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class UserDetails
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I believe `JsonUtility` serializes **fields** not properties.  See [Serialize and Deserialize Json and Json Array in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36239705/3744182) specifically ***4.TROUBLESHOOTING JsonUtility:** Remove property from the class.* and e.g. [Using JsonUtility.FromJson to deserialize JSON in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40545315/3744182).  So you would need `public string Id; ` without the `get` and `set` to use `JsonUtility`.

Comment: See [script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html)

Comment: @JunedKhanMomin [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin/357437#357437)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @dbc for clarification. `JsonUtility` probably serializes **fields** not **properties**. In the question's case, adding `{ get; set; }` makes it a property. Using properties enables adding additional functionalities in the code. However, to make the code work with `JsonUtility` remove `get;` and `set;` from the code. But you will get very limited functionality by using Unity's inbuilt `JsonUtility`. But it has limitations. It will not work with advanced usage. For that use **fork of JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json** mentioned below it works with Unity's IL2CPP builds on Android and iOS and others.

Another method is, use **fork of JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json** from [Json-for-Unity](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity). The **GitHub** page contains detailed explanation of how to use, how to install, its features, etc. It works with mobile builds such as Android and iOS and other IL2CPP builds. The Package is open source and is supported by the developer, unlike **JSON.Net** plugin which is not updated since 2016.

Please note that using **[JSON.Net](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347)** is an option but it is not updated since 2016, hence might give problems in latest or upcoming versions of Unity.